# CVS: How to require approval for a commit?

Tags: cvs

Is it possible to require some sort of approval for commits? Similar to a PR being approved in Git.

Did some digging and found the following in the documentation:

> Some systems provide ways to ensure that changes or releases go through various steps, with various approvals as needed. Generally, one can accomplish this with CVS but it might be a little more work. In some cases you'll want to use the commitinfo, loginfo, rcsinfo, or verifymsg files, to require that certain steps be performed before cvs will allow a checkin. Also consider whether features such as branches and tags can be used to perform tasks such as doing work in a development tree and then merging certain changes over to a stable tree only once they have been proven.

We already enforce templates via `verifymsg` but that doesn't stop sloppy code from making it through.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a separate system on top of CVS. You mentioned PRs and git. Pull requests are not a core feature of git. They are provided by additional software or services like Github or Gitlab. So in a similar way, you will need to find a suitable system to do that.

The last time I used CVS for work was about six years ago and one of the things I did was set up some software called [ReviewBoard](https://www.reviewboard.org/) and created a code review process. You could do something similar. In this particular instance, it was set up on an internal server. There might be a cloud service you could use instead, but given how old CVS is I suspect you will have trouble finding one.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer! I actually didn't know that PRs weren't a feature of git - learn something new everyday! I'll look into ReviewBoard, thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I know it’s not the question you asked, but consider spending that research energy on a more modern version control system.